# Load timestamp in MatDatepicker from Cloud Firestore | Firebase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, angular-material

### Does not load date returned from Cloud Firestore.

After I made the dependencies updates from `package.json` to the latest versions, I had a change that impacted a lot on my application in **Angular 6**.

I can not load a value of type Timestamp into a field of type [DatePicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) returned by the **Cloud Firestore**.

Before I upgrade I was returning an object of type `Date ()` and after the updates is returning a **Cloud Firestore** `Timestamp`.

I believe there was some change in the type returned by Firebase in this update.

The Datepicker field must receive a `Date ()` object, not a `Timestamp`.

I would have to traverse all records returned from the Cloud Firestore and call the `toDate ()` method to get the `Date ()` object and load it into DatePicker.

Is there a way to change the typing of Datepicker to Timestamp?
Otherwise I can not receive a value of type Timestamp from **Cloud Firestore**.

[image]

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --open",
    "start-hmr": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr -sm=false",
    "start-hmr-sourcemaps": "ng serve --hmr -e=hmr",
    "build": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev",
    "build-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --dev --stats-json",
    "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod",
    "build-prod-stats": "node --max_old_space_size=6144 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --stats-json",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "bundle-report": "webpack-bundle-analyzer dist/stats.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "6.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.15",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "6.0.1",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "6.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "6.0.0",
    "@ngrx/effects": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "10.0.1",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "8.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "12.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-dnd": "4.0.0",
    "@types/express": "4.11.1",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.9.0",
    "angular-calendar": "0.24.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.6.0",
    "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.9",
    "body-parser": "1.18.3",
    "body-parser-zlib": "1.0.2",
    "chart.js": "2.7.2",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "2.5.6",
    "creditcard.js": "2.1.3",
    "d3": "5.2.0",
    "express": "4.16.3",
    "firebase": "5.0.3",
    "firebase-admin": "5.12.1",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "2.0.8",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "moment": "2.22.1",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-currency-mask": "5.3.1",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "0.2.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "6.0.0",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "1.0.10",
    "ngx-mask": "2.7.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "8.6.0",
    "perfect-scrollbar": "1.3.0",
    "prismjs": "1.14.0",
    "rxjs": "6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.1.0",
    "typescript": "2.7.2",
    "web-animations-js": "2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.6.0",
    "@angular/cli": "6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "6.0.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "2.1.3",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "1.4.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.108",
    "@types/node": "8.9.5",
    "codelyzer": "4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.3.1",
    "ts-node": "5.0.1",
    "tslint": "5.9.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "2.11.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the DatePicker type?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: `var date = new Date(unix_timestamp*1000);` I'm not sure to understand your issue, but if you want to get a date from a timestamp, this is it.

Comment: Before the update returned a Date () object.
I do not want to go through all the records returned from Firebase and turn into a Date () object.

Comment: So, you want the timestamp from a DatePicker?

Comment: I need the return of the Cloud Firestore to be a Date () object again because the MatDatePicker field only accepts a Date () object.

Comment: At the moment my application is trying to load a timestamp into a MatDatePicker, this field only accepts Date () object. This started to occur after the package.json dependency updates.

Comment: Just pass the returned data form the Cloud Firestore into a toDate() function defined as : `return Date(myTimestamp*1000);`

Comment: Can you post your code where you download date from firestore?

Comment: I also have the exact same problem. I also pass nested object to form builder. The best solution to me  would be to use a date adapter for the datepicker that also accept and return timestamps. Did you find a solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

Luiz, I came across your question just now as I'm upgrading an old app and coming across this same problem.

For me I'm only dealing with one date at a time and so I use the `toDate()` method on the Timestamp to allow the datepicker to consume it. Try to see if there's a way you can do this en masse (I'm sure you've long since solved this problem, but wanting to post in case anyone else finds this helpful).

In saving updates to the database I can save them back as Timestamps by using `firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(myDateValue)`.

https://medium.com/@Idan_Co/using-firebase-timestamp-with-angular-bootstraps-datepicker-317336be9923 may be helpful in gaining further understanding as it was instrumental in helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is something like this, So just convert timestamp to type Date

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

/** @title Datepicker selected value */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-value-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-value-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-value-example.css'],
})
export class DatepickerValueExample {
  date = new FormControl(new Date(unix_timestamp*1000)); // convert timestamp to date
  serializedDate = new FormControl((new Date()).toISOString());
}
```

html:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" placeholder="Angular forms" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: That way it will not work, because I use FormBuilder to build the data returned by the Cloud Firestore.

Comment: I can't help you if you don't post how you build your data

Answer (score 0):

I am some sort of new with Angular 9 and I had the same problem as yours. I know, there are so many ways to deal with this problem but I don't want to take too much time looking for a fancy way. I decided to choose the easiest one meanwhile my '**dateProp**' type isn't that much important so I changed from '**Date**' to '**any**'

```
export interface ExampleModel {
  id: string;
  ...
  dateProp: any;
  ...
}
```

Once I got data from Firebase's document I won't have any matter to access Timestamp property such as '**seconds**' or '**nanoseconds**':

```
t {seconds: 1591945200, nanoseconds: 0}
```

Next step, I will be able to create a Date object base on the timestamp I received from Firebase's document.

```
...    
public date;
public exampleModel: ExampleModel;

constructor(private exampleService: ExampleService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    ...
    if (this.exampleId != null){
      this.exampleService
        .getExampleById(this.exampleId)
        .subscribe((example: ExampleModel) => {
          this.exampleModel = example;
          if (this.exampleModel !== undefined){
            this.date = new FormControl(new Date(this.exampleModel?.dateProp.seconds * 1000));
          }
      });
    }
```

The final step is simple, I just assign the 'date' to [formControl]

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <input name="exampleDate" matInput [matDatepicker]="exampleDatePicker" [formControl]="date" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="exampleDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #exampleDatePicker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

This was the question from two years ago but I still write this solution because I hope my solution would help the next coming guy who would have the same sticky problem as mine. :D

Answer (score 0):

to convert date from Timestamp to date used by datepicker, you need to use `formatDate` from `@angular/common`. This is the documentation [Angular - formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate)

Formats a date according to locale rules.

- value `string | number | Date` : The date to format, as a Date, or a number (milliseconds since UTC epoch) or an [ISO date-time string](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime).
- format `string` : The date-time components to include. See `DatePipe` for details.
- locale `string` : A locale code for the locale format rules to use.
- timezone `string` : The time zone. A time zone offset from GMT (such as `+0430`), or a standard UTC/GMT or continental US time zone abbreviation. If not specified, uses host system settings. [Optional] Default is `undefined`.

  formatDate(value: string | number | Date, format: string, locale: string, timezone?: string): string

This is an example to patch value of input using `formBuilder`

```
this.exeampleForm.patchValue({
    date: formatDate(new Date(this.exeampleForm.get('date').value).setHours(12), 'dd-MM-yyyy@HH:mm:ss', 'fr_FR')
});
```